# python flask website on windows HTTP Error 500 - Internal server error

Tags: python, flask, iis, wfastcgi

I have set up a Python flask through IIS. I have set up IIS and wfastcgi. I have verified  below -

1. Install IIS and CGI
2. Install wfastcgi
3. Created webconfig file
4. Configure IIS directories and permissions

When i try to URL I am seeing below -

HTTP Error 500.0 - Internal Server Error
An unknown FastCGI error occurred

Most likely causes:
IIS received the request; however, an internal error occurred during the processing of the request. The root cause of this error depends on which module handles the request and what was happening in the worker process when this error occurred.
IIS was not able to access the web.config file for the Web site or application. This can occur if the NTFS permissions are set incorrectly.
IIS was not able to process configuration for the Web site or application.
The authenticated user does not have permission to use this DLL.
The request is mapped to a managed handler but the .NET Extensibility Feature is not installed.

Things you can try:
Ensure that the NTFS permissions for the web.config file are correct and allow access to the Web server's machine account.
Check the event logs to see if any additional information was logged.
Verify the permissions for the DLL.
Install the .NET Extensibility feature if the request is mapped to a managed handler.
Create a tracing rule to track failed requests for this HTTP status code. For more information about creating a tracing rule for failed requests, click here.

What I am missing please help

Comment: [HTTP 500](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#5xx_Server_Error) is a generic server-side error message. On its own it doesn't tell us anything useful. Any time you see this your first step should be to check your error logs for more detail.

Comment: wfastcgi is dead, https://stackoverflow.com/tags/wfastcgi/info